# How to flash/blink scroll indicators in UIScrollView?

Tags: ios

How can i flash/blink the scroll indicators in an UIScrollView for a discrete moment?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use this method in UIScrollView:

```
- (void)flashScrollIndicators
```

**Swift 5**

```
scrollView.flashScrollIndicators()
```

Comment: iSofTom i need the scroll indicator to flash until they begin scrolling the scroll view. Is that possible?

Comment: I don't think so. If you want that behavior you may hide the scroll indicators and re create custom scroll indicators. It's possible but there is a lot of work.

Comment: The method is called `- (void) flashScrollers`

Comment: In NSScrollView the method name is `flashScrollers`, in `UIScrollView` it's `flashScrollIndicators`.